# Ubuntu 22.04 - NFS fail to start due to missing depencies - systemd-networkd-wait-online.service and proc-fs-nfsd.mount fail to start as well

Tags: 22.04, nfs

I'm trying to install NFS for my VPS server however it fails to start - it shows that is due to missing dependencies:

[sudo systemctl status nfs-server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3f2Op.png)

```
 root@server:/# sudo systemctl status nfs-server
 ○ nfs-server.service - NFS server and services
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nfs-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
 Active: inactive (dead)

 Feb 16 19:36:39 server systemd[1]: Dependency failed for NFS server and services.
 Feb 16 19:36:39 server systemd[1]: nfs-server.service: Job nfs-server.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
 Feb 16 19:36:39 server systemd[1]: Dependency failed for NFS server and services.
 Feb 16 19:36:39 server systemd[1]: nfs-server.service: Job nfs-server.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
 Feb 16 19:42:12 server systemd[1]: Dependency failed for NFS server and services.
 Feb 16 19:42:12 server systemd[1]: nfs-server.service: Job nfs-server.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
 Feb 19 12:30:54 server systemd[1]: Dependency failed for NFS server and services.
 Feb 19 12:30:54 server systemd[1]: nfs-server.service: Job nfs-server.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
 Feb 19 12:30:55 server systemd[1]: Dependency failed for NFS server and services.
 Feb 19 12:30:55 server systemd[1]: nfs-server.service: Job nfs-server.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
```

nfs dependencies list:

[systemctl list-dependencies nfs-kernel-server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBAUy.png)

```
 root@server:/# systemctl list-dependencies nfs-kernel-server
 nfs-kernel-server.service
 ○ ├─auth-rpcgss-module.service
 ○ ├─nfs-idmapd.service
 ○ ├─nfs-mountd.service
 ○ ├─nfsdcld.service
 × ├─proc-fs-nfsd.mount
 ● ├─rpc-statd-notify.service
 ● ├─rpc-statd.service
 ○ ├─rpc-svcgssd.service
 ● ├─rpcbind.socket
 ● ├─system.slice
 ● ├─network-online.target
 ● │ ├─ifupdown-wait-online.service
 ● │ ├─networking.service
 × │ └─systemd-networkd-wait-online.service
 ● └─network.target
```

It seems that proc-fs-nfsd.mount and systemd-networkd-wait-online.service are missing.

[sudo systemctl status proc-fs-nfsd.mount](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4wCC.png)

```
 × proc-fs-nfsd.mount - NFSD configuration filesystem
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/proc-fs-nfsd.mount; static)
 Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2024-02-19 12:30:55 UTC; 1h 28min ago
  Where: /proc/fs/nfsd
   What: nfsd

 Feb 19 12:30:55 server systemd[1]: Mounting NFSD configuration filesystem...
 Feb 19 12:30:55 server mount[1997336]: mount: /proc/fs/nfsd: unknown filesystem type 'nfsd'.
 Feb 19 12:30:55 server systemd[1]: proc-fs-nfsd.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited, status=32/n/a
 Feb 19 12:30:55 server systemd[1]: proc-fs-nfsd.mount: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
 Feb 19 12:30:55 server systemd[1]: Failed to mount NFSD configuration filesystem.
```

It seems that nfsd doesn't start because the OS can't read nfsd files.

[sudo systemctl status systemd-networkd-wait-online.service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hzapj.png)

```
× systemd-networkd-wait-online.service - Wait for Network to be Configured
 Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/systemd-networkd-wait-online.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
 Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2024-02-19 12:26:07 UTC; 1h 30min ago
   Docs: man:systemd-networkd-wait-online.service(8)
Main PID: 1996517 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Feb 19 12:24:07 server systemd[1]: Starting Wait for Network to be Configured...
Feb 19 12:26:07 server systemd[1]: systemd-networkd-wait-online.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 19 12:26:07 server systemd[1]: systemd-networkd-wait-online.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 19 12:26:07 server systemd[1]: Failed to start Wait for Network to be Configured.
```

And systemd-networkd-wait-online.service fail with exit-code.

journalctl

[journalctl -xeu nfs-server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LALcZ.png)

```
Feb 19 12:30:54 server systemd[1]: Dependency failed for NFS server and services.
Subject: A start job for unit nfs-server.service has failed
Defined-By: systemd
Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support

A start job for unit nfs-server.service has finished with a failure.

The job identifier is 33900 and the job result is dependency.
Feb 19 12:30:54 server systemd[1]: nfs-server.service: Job nfs-    server.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Feb 19 12:30:55 server systemd[1]: Dependency failed for NFS server and services.
Subject: A start job for unit nfs-server.service has failed
Defined-By: systemd
Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support

A start job for unit nfs-server.service has finished with a failure.

The job identifier is 33930 and the job result is dependency.
Feb 19 12:30:55 server systemd[1]: nfs-server.service: Job nfs-server.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
```

[journalctl -xeu systemd-networkd-wait-online.service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afZ2U.png)

```
Feb 19 12:26:07 server systemd[1]: systemd-networkd-wait-online.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Subject: Unit process exited
Defined-By: systemd
Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support

An ExecStart= process belonging to unit systemd-networkd-wait-online.service has exited.

The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
Feb 19 12:26:07 server systemd[1]: systemd-networkd-wait-online.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Subject: Unit failed
Defined-By: systemd
Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support

The unit systemd-networkd-wait-online.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 19 12:26:07 server systemd[1]: Failed to start Wait for     Network to be Configured.
Subject: A start job for unit systemd-networkd-wait-online.service has failed
Defined-By: systemd
Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support

A start job for unit systemd-networkd-wait-online.service has finished with a failure.

The job identifier is 33872 and the job result is failed.
```

[journalctl -xeu proc-fs-nfsd.mount](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igwZ3.png)

```
Feb 19 12:30:55 server systemd[1]: Mounting NFSD configuration filesystem...
Subject: A start job for unit proc-fs-nfsd.mount has begun execution
Defined-By: systemd
Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support

A start job for unit proc-fs-nfsd.mount has begun execution.

The job identifier is 33931.
Feb 19 12:30:55 server mount[1997336]: mount: /proc/fs/nfsd:             unknown filesystem type 'nfsd'.
Feb 19 12:30:55 server systemd[1]: proc-fs-nfsd.mount: Mount     process exited, code=exited, status=32/n/a
Subject: Unit process exited
Defined-By: systemd
Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support

An n/a= process belonging to unit proc-fs-nfsd.mount has exited.

The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 32.
Feb 19 12:30:55 server systemd[1]: proc-fs-nfsd.mount: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Subject: Unit failed
Defined-By: systemd
Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support

The unit proc-fs-nfsd.mount has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 19 12:30:55 server systemd[1]: Failed to mount NFSD configuration filesystem.
Subject: A start job for unit proc-fs-nfsd.mount has failed
Defined-By: systemd

Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support

A start job for unit proc-fs-nfsd.mount has finished with a failure.

The job identifier is 33931 and the job result is failed.
```

I googled about it and it seems that those dependencies are missing in some images on web servers and the only way is to install a new image with the dependencies installed.

Is there some way to install those dependencies and make NFS work without formating the system?

EDIT: Changed the ubuntu version on the title and add log text for commands

Comment: It would be really helpful for everyone if you pasted the text of the logs in the question rather than a series of screenshots.

Comment: Sorry i'm new to using ubuntu server terminal, i will fiz my question.

Comment: Sorry wrong spelling

Comment: Added the text log to the question.

Comment: I don't know exactly what the OP was refering as "install a different kernel flavor", is that fomating the web server? is it not? Can i just install the new kernel? how can i do it?

Comment: What do you get when you run `modprobe nfsd` if it's not found, `sudo apt install linux-image-generic` , remove the other kernel, and reboot

Comment: Is it safe? Is there any complications that may happen if i do it? I don't want to lose any information on the web server i'm trying to install NFS(It is the web server from my job).

Comment: It's safe and is the kernel most people use for desktop. You could always switch back to and reinstall the original kernel

Comment: Thanks! i will try to switch the kernel!